# Skype can't access sound card in Windows XP connected via RDP

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, skype

I'm on Windows XP Professional. From this machine, I'm connecting via RDP to another Windows XP Professional machine. Now when I go to Skype to place a voice call on the remote machine, it says that it can't access the sound card.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Skype running over RDP is not supported.

This is for 2 reasons:

1. The latency involved, and the bandwidth constraints, would make it a very poor experience, and Skype don't like giving their customers poor experiences.
2. More importantly - RDP doesn't support incoming sound - only outgoing sound - so you don't actually have a microphone available in RDP.

There may be some third-party application which would give you a virtual microphone over the network, but it's not something that I would relish doing unless I was on a very fast connection to the target machine.